# Cannot install PHP7 to AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

I have successfully installed apache 2.4.34 onto my instance but I am unable to install PHP7.  I have tried the following:

```
 sudo yum install php70
```

But I get the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No package php70 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: what operation system are you running?

Comment: `sudo yum install php7.0-zip`
can you try run this command?

Comment: @pr1nc3 i get the same error as above.

Comment: I posted an answer to fix it in two steps. We had quite a similar issue and we fixed it that way. Hope it helps

Comment: Figure out what the right package name is: `yum search php`

Answer (score 2):

It could be possible that you are missing the right name. Check what php version is there with the command:

```
yum search php70
```

After that you should see a php version name. Copy and paste it to your command like:

```
yum install <php version name>
```

Make sure you put the whole php version name and don't forget to restart your apache!!!

Answer (score -1):

`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`
`apt-get install software-properties-common`
`add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
`apt-get update`
`apt-get install php<Your desired version>`

Confirm it installed by running:
`php -V`